# Tweepy based Bot Not working

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have created a twitter Bot using `python` with the following code

```
import tweepy, time, sys
argfile = str(sys.argv[1])
#enter the corresponding information from your Twitter application:
CONSUMER_KEY ='********'#keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer key
CONSUMER_SECRET ='*******'#keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer secret key
ACCESS_KEY ='*********'#keep the quotes, replace this with your access token
ACCESS_SECRET ='********'#keep the quotes, replace this with your access token secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()
###### 
for line in f:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(900)#Tweet every 15 minutes

#### Code is ready
#### next to create the API for twitter
```

The message I wish to post is in a separate text file-

**HelloWorld.txt**

```
Hello World!!!
Lots of Noise here
!!!!
I am tweeting. I wish to learn automation!!!!
```

The last step involves using the following command in the command line

```
"helloworld.py" "HelloWorld.txt"
```

The code works fine. **The tweet is however not working**. I have Added the key and secret codes correctly after authorizing the bot to tweet. 
Will be grateful if someone can help me understand the bug.

Comment: If your code working fine & not able to tweet then possible error could be
1. Your text is more than 140 char long
2. Duplicate status.You may posted same status previously.

BTW log or print the API response. It will tell the exact problem

Comment: Thank you Sir. The tweet is short so I think I can rule that out. I will check the API response. That may have the solution.

Comment: What error are you seeing from the Twitter API?